# How do you extend a CouchDB Docker Image to include schema + seed data

Tags: docker, dockerfile, couchdb

I’m trying to extend CouchDB docker image in order to pre-populate CouchDB. I have a second image that, when started, looks for a CouchDB instance, sets up schema, and then runs a seed script that populates the DB.

I know how to orchestrate this with docker-compose, but ideally, I would like to create and publish a custom CouchDB docker image that has the schema + data already seeded to speed things up.

I think I need to use a docker "builder" to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how to spin up the CouchDB image within the builder to do the seed.

Comment: Like the other standard Docker Hub database images, you can't create a derived image with prepopulated data.  Unlike the other standard Docker Hub database images, there's not a standard place to put a database dump or initialization script.  The loader container you have seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: I actually forgot I made [my own couchdb docker image](https://github.com/dominicbarnes/docker-couchdb) that basically does this, if you find that useful.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything currently built in for this, and I've wanted something similar as well! It should be possible to add, and it might even be possible to contribute back [upstream](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker).

I would probably take inspiration from other database images, such as [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (see "Initialization scripts"), which execute scripts stored in a specific directory to bootstrap the container. In the case of postgres, this can be used to provision database schemas or install plugins, which sounds very much like what you're asking here.

One potential risk with maintaining your own image here is keeping it up-to-date as new versions of CouchDB come out, which is the main reason I would at least attempt getting something committed to the original repo.